# Unpack Proto3 Any in Java

Tags: java, serialization, binary, deserialization, protocol-buffers

I want to use a Protocol Buffer Message in a Java project, but I don't know what type will be used during runtime. It can be a simple datatype or another message object.

Example:

proto file:

```
...
message MyMessage {
    repeated google.protobuf.Any params = 1;
}
...
```

to serialize my values, I use the following code (type of payload is unknown):

```
Any.Builder anyBuilder = Any.newBuilder();
ByteString byteString;
if (ClassUtils.isPrimitiveOrWrapper(payload.getClass())) {
      byte[] serialize = SerializationUtils.serialize((Serializable) payload);
      byteString = ByteString.copyFrom(serialize);
} else {
      //serialize custom message
}
anyBuilder.setValue(byteString);

myMessage.addParams(Any.pack(anyBuilder.build()));
```

to deserialize my values, I use the following code:

```
List<Any> paramsList = myMessage.getParamsList();
Object[] objects = new Object[paramsList.size()];
int i = 0;
for (Any any : paramsList) {
    ByteString value = any.getValue();
    objects[i++] = SerializationUtils.deserialize(value.toByteArray());
}
```

The code throws **org.apache.commons.lang3.SerializationException: java.io.EOFException**

Can I use SerializationUtils#serialize for a independent communication (e.g. Java to Python; Java to C++) at all or do I have to use something else?

Can I use any in Proto3 for a simple datatype or is it restricted to proto messages?

Thanks!